# What does Eigensystem::geinsl1 mean (a solution for the generalized eigenproblem may be incorrect)?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, warning-messages

I'm trying to solve a generalized eigenvalue problem and ran across a warning

> Eigensystem::geinsl1: Warning: a solution for the generalized eigenproblem may be incorrect.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
A = a IdentityMatrix[3];
B = b IdentityMatrix[3];
Eigensystem[{A, B}]
```

> Eigensystem::geinsl1: Warning: a solution for the generalized
>   eigenproblem may be incorrect.
>
> `{{a/b, a/b, a/b}, {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}}`

What is this warning really saying? That it can't check the answer? According to the documentation, the generalized eigenproblem solution satisfies the equation

```
m.Transpose[vectors] == a.Transpose[vectors].DiagonalMatrix[values]
```

which `FullSimplify` doesn't seem to have any problems with:

```
FullSimplify[A.Transpose[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}] == B.Transpose[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}].DiagonalMatrix[{a/b, a/b, a/b}]]
```

> `True`

Thus the answer seems to be perfectly fine and WL is capable of checking it, so why the warning? Are there cases where the solution is actually incorrect? In this case, the culprit seems to be that the eigenvalues are all the same. Changing $B$ to

```
B = b {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}
```

and computing the same eigenproblem, the warning disappears.

I'm running V12.1 on macOS.

---

**Edit:** running `Eigenvalues` and `CharacteristicPolynomial` works fine, but `Eigenvectors` spits out the same warning:

[image: Running Eigenvalues, Eigenvectors and CharacteristicPolynomial]

Comment: I don't get the warning on 11.2. What version is this? What you have is a perfectly admissible pencil, so there shouldn't be any trouble with generating its eigensystem.

Comment: I’m on version 12.1, added this to the question too.

Comment: Just for consistency checking: do you get similar warning messages for `Eigenvalues[{A, B}]`, `Eigenvectors[{A, B}]`, and `CharacteristicPolynomial[{A, B}, x]`?

Comment: The warning appears only on `Eigenvectors`, see edit (`Eigenvectors` returns a matrix, which is because I've set MMA to display 2D arrays as matrices by default)